# How to get data from SQL for weeks. First day Monday

Tags: sql, date, group-by, sqlanywhere, week-number

I am from Europe. First day of the week Monday

Тhis is my code:

```
set datefirst 1;

select DATEPART(wk, did_dat) as Data, sum(sum_cre) as Suma 
from view_didknobj1 
where sas_kod between '505' and '505'  
  and did_dat between '2019.12.23' and '2019.12.29' 
group by DATEPART(wk, did_dat) 
order by DATEPART(wk, did_dat) asc
```

This data is returned from this query:

[image]

it should be like that: 52:  23669.77

Comment: SQL Anywhere Server

Comment: Did you try setting the [`first_day_of_week=1`](http://dcx.sap.com/1200/en/dbadmin/first-day-of-week-option.html) [connection property](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbprogramming/jdbc-url-driver.html)?

Comment: Yes. Same result

Comment: Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

Execute above sql command

Comment: Yes. in 1 line write